# How do I make this loop through an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this jquery code:

```
function(returnArray){
     for (i=0; i<returnArray.length; i++) {
         $('<li class="tagSuggestTag"/>').appendTo('#tagSuggest ul').text(returnArray[i]);
     }
```

return array is an array, but for some reason when I do this it loops through every letter of the array instead of each value in the array.

The returnArray is `["hello", "helloe", "helloer"]` and that loop goes through and returns:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure returnArray is an array? It looks like it's the string '["hello", "helloe", "helloer"]'.

Comment: Seems like `returnArray` is a string (especially since the first output char is a `[`) - could you post the code that creates it?

Comment: @Dunes @Anders Lindahl actually it might be now that I think about it. It is coming for a php echo of a json_encode() of an array. Any idea if that would return a string?

Comment: If thats true any idea how I would do a loop like thing just with the string, I am assuming I should use regexp just not sure exactly what after that

Comment: If it's in json format and you're using jquery, why not use the jQuery.parseJSON function? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: @Anders Lindahl thanks, thats exactly what I needed! You should put that as an answer so I can mark it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was revealed in the comments to the question that the `returnarray` isn't really an array, it's a JSON string representation of a string computed by the PHP function `json_encode()`.

The function [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) can turn this back into a javascript array.

Answer (score 1):

your array is a string. use:

```
var myarray = eval('["hello", "helloe", "helloer"]');
```

Comment: euuw - why eval? `var myarray = ["hello", "helloe", "helloer"];` will work

Comment: because returnArray IS A STRING not an array. this was just an example of how to convert a string representation of an array to an actual array. the real code would be var realArray = eval(returnArray);